# How to add UITextField to SKScene (SpriteKit Game)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've searched endlessly for a solution to this. Many of the questions already opened are either not answered or very vague in explanation.

I am trying to add a UITextField to my SKScene as players need to be able to create an account for this game.

```
var txtField:UITextField!
```

Here I declare the text field.

```
txtField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY, width: 200, height: 30));
view.addSubview(txtField!)
```

With these two lines I'm trying to add the text field as a subview. When I run the app, the text field is not visible. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to change the zPosition of this subview?

Would really appreciate some help on this! :)

Comment: "How to add UITextField to SKScene (SpriteKit Game)"  UITextField does not belong to SKScene.  Period.

Comment: @ElTomato sorry about that. I've removed the "SKScene" tag now. New here :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a `UITextField` onto the scene, be sure to call `addSubview` with the visible `SKView`, you may check the following code:

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let sceneFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
var scene = SKScene(size: sceneFrame.size)
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

let textFieldFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
let textField = UITextField(frame: textFieldFrame)
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
textField.placeholder = "hello world"

let skView = SKView(frame: sceneFrame)
skView.addSubview(textField)
skView.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skView
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: This worked - thanks for this. I was adding the subview in my "Launch" scene file instead of in the GameViewController.

Comment: How would I go about referencing this subview inside my game scene?

Comment: This works **unless** we call presentScene with a SKTransition. If so, the textField just sits there waiting for the transition to finish. Any ideas to get **both** to transition **together**?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came up with two functions that can help here for the future.

```
func createTextField (at: CGPoint, size: CGSize, isSecure: Bool = false) -> NSTextField {
    var newSize = size
    newSize.width *= (self.view?.frame.width)! / self.frame.width
    newSize.height *= (self.view?.frame.height)! / self.frame.height

    var pos = convertPoint(toView: at)
    pos.x -= (newSize.width / 2)
    pos.y -= (newSize.height / 2)

    return !isSecure ? NSTextField (frame: NSRect (x: pos.x, y: pos.y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)) : NSSecureTextField (frame: NSRect (x: pos.x, y: pos.y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
}

func createTextField (spriteNamed: String, isSecure: Bool = false) -> NSTextField {
    let node = self.childNode(withName: spriteNamed) as! SKSpriteNode
    let pos = convert(node.position, from: node.parent!)

    node.removeFromParent()

    return createTextField(at: pos, size: node.size, isSecure: isSecure)
}
```

These functions allow you to add a ordinary SKSpriteNode to your Scene and have them be replaced by NSTextFields.