# I want to add an editable text field to a SpriteKit Scene but can't get it to show up

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I tried to add a UITextField object to my SpriteKit scene to have an editable name but it won't show up. Is there a better way to do this in SpriteKit? Or am I just doing it wrong?

I tried to add a UITextField and then add it to the scene. It did not show up at all.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class CharacterCreatorView: SKScene{
    
    var charName: String
    var charRace: Race
    var charClass: String
    var charStr: Int
    var charCon: Int
    var charIntl: Int
    var charWis: Int
    var doneButton: SKShapeNode
    var editCharName: UITextField = UITextField()
    
    
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        // variable values
        self.charName = "Astra"
        self.charRace = .human
        self.charClass = "Apprentice Mage"
        self.charStr = 5
        self.charCon = 5
        self.charIntl = 5
        self.charWis = 5
        let w = 300, h = 100
        
        // done button
        self.doneButton = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: Int(size.width)/2-w/2, y: 200-h, width: w, height: h))
        self.doneButton.fillColor = UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 229/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        let doneText = SKLabelNode(text: "Finished!")
        self.doneButton.addChild(doneText)
        doneText.position = CGPoint(x: Int(size.width)/2, y: 200-h/2)
        doneText.fontName = "Helvetica-Bold"
        doneText.fontSize = 40

        // editable text node
        
        super.init(size: size)
        self.view?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
        self.addChild(self.doneButton)
        
        if let view = self.view {
            let x = (view.frame.width - 200) / 2
            let y = (view.frame.height - 50) / 2
            self.editCharName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 200, height: 50))
            self.editCharName.placeholder = "Enter character name"
            self.editCharName.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            view.addSubview(self.editCharName)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: i've never had luck using normal GUI widgets from UIKit/AppKit. easiest solution is to use SwiftUI (or UIKit/AppKit) in a transparent-background layer over the top of SpriteKit.

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896748/how-to-add-uitextfield-to-skscene-spritekit-game